# For loop using decimals

Tags: r, for-loop

I was wondering if I could create a for loop where i goes up by decimals. I have tried writing:

```
for (i in seq(2,6,.1)) 
{
   data1 <- data[data$x1 > i,]
   model <- lm(y~x1, data = data1)
   r = summary(model1)$r.squared
   result[[i]] = r
}
```

but the result only gives 5 observations from taking only the integers from 2-6.

Is there a way to get around this.

Comment: Please show more of your code because the part you showed is correct

Comment: I just edited it (not properly but I am a new user) to show the code

Comment: `i` being a decimal `result[[i]]` does not have a meaning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result[[i]]` inside your loop will never work with decimal values of `i`,
because list indexes must be integers.

Other than that, you can loop in increments of `.1`, if you change the way you think about `.1` increments:

```
for (i in seq(20, 60)) {
  div <- i / 10
  data1 <- data[data$x1 > div,]
  model <- lm(y~x1, data = data1)
  result[[i]] = summary(model1)$r.squared
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you did that is not the best in R. That way is better (but not the best). However it is close to your original code.

```
data = data.frame(y = runif(100),  x1 = runif(1000, 1,7))

f = function(x, data)
{
  data1 <- data[data$x1 > x,]
  model <- lm(y ~ x1, data = data1)
  r <- summary(model)$r.squared
  return(r)
}

results = lapply(seq(2,6,.1), f, data)
```